# Operator overloading on += for set and get calls wrong setter

Tags: kotlin

I have made an extension functions for BigIntegers, allowing me to add Ints to them.

```
operator fun BigInteger.plus(other: Int): BigInteger = this + other.toBigInteger()
// Allowing me to do
val c = myBigInt + 3
```

I have also made a Counter class, holding bigintegers for various keys, for easy counting. Since doing `counter["1"] += myBigInt` isn't allowed on standard maps (it's nullable), I have added a custom getter that returns a default value, making this possible.

```
class Counter<K>(val map: MutableMap<K, BigInteger>) : MutableMap<K, BigInteger> by map {
    constructor() : this(mutableMapOf())

    override operator fun get(key: K): BigInteger {
        return map.getOrDefault(key, BigInteger.ZERO)
    }
```

I can then use it like this

```
val counter = Counter<String>()
c["ones"] += 5.toBigInteger()
```

Problem is that I cannot use it like this:

```
c["ones"] += 5 // doesn't work, "Kotlin: No set method providing array access"
```

but this should be equivalent to this, which works, since it should use my extension operator on the bigint:

```
c["ones"] = c["ones"] + 5 // works
```

**Why doesn't this work?**

I've tried adding a set method for Ints, but then I see a *very weird behavior*. Kotlin will do the calculation correct, but then convert the BigInteger to an Int before passing it to my class! Example:

```
inline operator fun BigInteger.plus(other: Int): BigInteger {
    val bigInteger = this + other.toBigInteger()
    println("calculated bigint to $bigInteger")
    return bigInteger
}
class Counter<K>(val map: MutableMap<K, BigInteger>) : MutableMap<K, BigInteger> by map {
    constructor() : this(mutableMapOf())

    override operator fun get(key: K): BigInteger {
        return map.getOrDefault(key, BigInteger.ZERO)
    }

    operator fun set(key: K, value: Int) {
        println("setting int $value")
        map[key] = value.toBigInteger()
    }
}
val c = Counter<String>()
c["1"] = "2192039569601".toBigInteger()
c["1"] += 5
println("result: ${c["1"]}")
c["1"] = "2192039569601".toBigInteger()
c["1"] = c["1"] + 5
println("result: ${c["1"]}")
```

Which prints

```
calculated bigint to 2192039569606
setting int 1606248646 <--- why does it call the int setter here?
result: 1606248646

calculated bigint to 2192039569606
result: 2192039569606
```

**Why does Kotlin do the BigInt summation, but converts it back to an Int before sending to my setter?**

### Update

Since a comment suggest this is a [compiler issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-24809), any other ideas?
My ultimate goal here, was to have a counter of big integers, but to be able to easily add ints to it.

Adding this as a set function, makes it being called for both ints and bigints, so I can do the proper assignment myself. However, it will also then allow someone to add floats that will crash at runtime.

```
operator fun set(key: K, value: Number) {
    map[key] = when (value) {
        is BigInteger -> value
        is Int -> value.toBigInteger()
        else -> throw RuntimeException("only ints")
    }
}
```

Any tips?

Comment: Looks like the bug reported in [KT-24809](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-24809).

Comment: Hmm, thanks @Sweeper I will have to think more about the design then

Comment: Can you not declare the `set` to take `BigInteger` and let the caller be the one to call `toBigInteger` if all they have on hand is an `Int`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yup. I'd like to avoid it if possible to make it prettier, though. I thought I had it working with the custom setter, only later discovered it overflowed since it did an invisible cast to Int.

Comment: I can think of a solution that involves creating a mutable wrapper for `BigInteger`, and making `Counter` be a `MutableMap<K, MutableBigInteger>`. Which means that putting `BigInteger`s into the counter would be more cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that `c["ones"] += 5` can be translated into calls in two ways:

```
c.set("ones", c.get("ones").plus(5))

c.get("ones").plusAssign(5)
```

The first way is what your code currently translates to, because you don't have a `plusAssign` operator defined. As I said in the comments, there is a [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-24809) in the compiler that prevents the operators from resolved correctly. When resolving `c["ones"] += 5`, It seems to be trying to find a `set` operator that takes an `Int` instead (possibly because `5` is an `Int`), which is unexpected. If you modify the code in the bug report a little, you can even make it throw an exception when executed!

```
class Foo {
    operator fun get(i: Int) : A = A()
    operator fun set(i: Int, a: A) {}
    operator fun set(i: Int, a: Int) {}
}
class A {
    operator fun plus(b: Int) = A()
}

class B
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val foo = Foo()
    foo[0] = foo[0] + 1
    foo[0] += 1 // this compiles now, since there is a set(Int, Int) method
                // but A can't be casted to Int, so ClassCastException!
}
```

It is rather coincidental (and lucky) in your case, that the compiler knows how to convert from `BigInteger` (or any other `Number` type actually) to `Int`, using `Number#intValue`. Otherwise the program would have crashed too.

---

A natural alternative way is to define the `plusAssign` operator, so that the assignment gets translated the second way. However, we can't do it on `BigInteger`, because `plusAssign` would need to mutate `this`, but `BigInteger` is immutable. This means that we need to create our own mutable wrapper. This does mean that you lose the nice immutability, but this is all I can think of.

```
fun main() {
    val c = Counter<String>()
    c.set("1", "2192039569601".toMutableBigInteger())
    c.get("1").plusAssign(5)
    println("result: ${c["1"]}")
}

data class MutableBigInteger(var bigInt: BigInteger) {
    operator fun plusAssign(other: Int) {
        bigInt += other.toBigInteger()
    }
}

fun String.toMutableBigInteger() = MutableBigInteger(toBigInteger())

class Counter<K>(val map: MutableMap<K, MutableBigInteger>) : MutableMap<K, MutableBigInteger> by map{
    constructor() : this(mutableMapOf())

    override operator fun get(key: K): MutableBigInteger {
        return map.getOrPut(key) { MutableBigInteger(BigInteger.ZERO) }
    }

    operator fun set(key: K, value: Int) {
        println("setting int $value")
        map[key] = MutableBigInteger(value.toBigInteger())
    }

}
```

Notably, `getOrDefault` is changed to `getOrPut` - when a value is not found, we want to put the zero we return into the map, rather than just returning a zero that is not in the map. Our changes to that instance wouldn't be visible through the map otherwise.

Comment: I'd say it was unlucky, as it meant I had a bug that gave wrong answers for big numbers, instead of crashing :') Thanks for your thoughts!